# Stata sum/average over a range

Tags: loops, sum, average, stata

With the following dataset.

```
id    date       date1a    date1b    date2a     date2b    variable
1   1/1/2000    2/6/2009  8/9/2009  7/14/2010  9/2/2010      7
1   1/2/2000    2/6/2009  8/9/2009  7/14/2010  9/2/2010      2
1   1/2/2000    2/6/2009  8/9/2009  7/14/2010  9/2/2010     11
...
1   1/1/2013    2/6/2009  8/9/2009  7/14/2010  9/2/2010      9
1   1/8/2013    2/6/2009  8/9/2009  7/14/2010  9/2/2010      8
2   2/2/2010    6/1/2010  7/9/2011  4/6/2012   5/1/2012      4
2   2/2/2010    6/1/2010  7/9/2011  4/6/2012   5/1/2012      3
2   2/2/2010    6/1/2010  7/9/2011  4/6/2012   5/1/2012      1
...
2   5/1/2012    6/1/2010  7/9/2011  4/6/2012   5/1/2012     1
2   5/1/2012    6/1/2010  7/9/2011  4/6/2012   5/1/2012     1
```

I would like to create the variables `sum1` and `average1` and `sum2` and `average2`,  which fulfill those operation for `variable` between the dates ranges of `date1a` to `date1b` (for `sum1` and `average1`) and `date2a` to `date2b` (for `sum2` and `average2`).

Right now, my method is laborious, prone to error, and is not capturing the fact that I have duplicate entries for the same day. Also, if there is no `date` that matches `date1b` or `date2b` then I need to manually make edits.

```
sort date
gen date1range = date1b - date1a
local j = date1range
forval i = 1/`j' {
    by id: gen variableforcalc`i' = variable[_n-`i']
}
egen sum1 = rowtotal(variableforcalc*)
egen average1 = rowmean(variableforcalc*)
gen dateflag = 0
replace dateflag = 1 if date == date1b
```

Comment: Must averages be for the same `id`?

Comment: @NickCox It is all within `id`, I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: I still think you need to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stopped reading your code when I saw

```
local j = date1range
```

which is going to be interpreted as

```
local j = date1range[1]
```

and so can't be the basis of a general solution.

You can initialise

```
 gen sum1 = . 
 gen average1 = .
```

and group according to identical `id`, `date1a` and `date1b`

```
 egen group = group(id date1a date1b) 
 su group, meanonly
```

Then you loop over the distinct values of `group`

```
 quietly forval j = 1/`r(max)' { 
     * start and end dates and id should be identical in each group; this is just look-up 
     su date1a if group == `j', meanonly  
     local d1 = r(min) 
     su date1b if group == `j', meanonly 
     local d2 = r(min) 
     su id if group == `j', meanonly 
     local this = r(min) 

     su variable if id == `this' & inrange(date, `d1', `d2'), meanonly 
     replace sum1 = r(sum) if group == `j' 
     replace mean1 = r(mean) if group == `j' 
}
```

The other sum and mean should be amenable to the same treatment.

Some problems with loosely similar structure are discussed in http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0033